# How to obtain sine wave back after fft?

Tags: matlab, fft, sine

I performed fft in matlab on y=sin(2*pi*t), with a time period of T=0.015. Now I want to get the original function back in the time domain, but I'm not sure how I can use ifft to do that. It gives me the wrong answer each time. Could someone please explain to me how to go about this?

Comment: What happens when you try ifft?

Comment: This is not about EE. Would would better try other stackexchange sites: math, or stackoverflow for matlab.

Comment: There is actually dsp stackexchange, it might be a good fit if the problem with IFFT is in understanding of the procedure. In any case, before thingking about migrating this question,we need to actually know what's happening. Please post the exact code you're using and the results you get.

Comment: Did you take only the real part of ifft?

Comment: Whatever.  Finally when we have specific stack exchange sites for each problem, then everything will be so splintered you can't figure anything out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a bit of MATLAB code that does work (16,384 point FFT on a 240 second sample, padded with zeros).

```
dt = 0.015;
tmax = 240;
x = 0:dt:tmax;
y = sin(2*pi*x);
N = 2^14;
transformed_y = fft(y,N)*dt;
ft = 1/dt;
f = (0:(N-1)/2)/N*ft;
recovered_y = ifft(transformed_y,N,'symmetric')/dt;
x_recovered = 0:1/ft:(length(recovered_y)-1)*1/ft;
plot(x_recovered, recovered_y,'g')
```

[image]

(and zoom in to the beginning of the plot)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're starting with a 1-Hz sine wave, but you're sampling it with a period of 0.015 seconds, which corresponds to a sample rate of 66.667 samples/second.

Because of this non-integer relationship between the signal frequency and the sample rate, your "signal" (the sine wave) doesn't fall squarely into a single "freqeuncy bin" of the FFT result; instead, you get "spillover" into adjacent bins.

When you try to reconstruct the time-domain signal, this spillover causes what appears to be distortion of the waveform — although if you check carefully, the reconstructed waveform has the same values as the original waveform *at the original sampling points*.